# Count where previous record exists in either of two tables

Tags: postgresql, count

I'm trying to `COUNT` records on one table where both the counted records and their "previous" records exist either in the same table or on another.

The table that I'm sampling has a composite `PRIMARY KEY` consisting of a `bigint` and `character`.  The other table has the same structure.

A "previous" record has the same `character` and a `bigint - 1` as the counted record either on the same table or on the other table.

In pseudo:

```
counting_table
   character_column
   bigint_column

other_table
   character_column
   bigint_column
```

`counting_table` will never have a parallel record on `other_table` because the parallel record on `counting_table` is deleted when its primary key equivalent is inserted into `other_table`.

I thought I could do this with subqueries, but I can't seem to figure out how to access the outer query's data from inside the subquery.

How can my intent be implemented optimally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to `LEFT JOIN` both tables (`counting_table` itself as well as `other_table`), and count a `COALESCE` expression, which will be `NULL` (and therefore not counted) if neither table has a "previous" record:

```
SELECT count(COALESCE(o.bigint_col, c1.bigint_col)) AS ct
FROM   counting_table c
LEFT   JOIN other_table o ON o.bigint_col = c.bigint_col - 1
                         AND o.char_col   = c.char_col
LEFT   JOIN counting_table c1 ON c1.bigint_col = c.bigint_col - 1
                             AND c1.char_col   = c.char_col;
```

The other option would be with two OR'ed [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-joins:

```
SELECT count(*) AS ct
FROM   counting_table c
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM other_table o
   WHERE  o.bigint_col = c.bigint_col - 1
   AND    o.char_col   = c.char_col
   )
OR    EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM counting_table c1
   WHERE  c1.bigint_col = c.bigint_col - 1
   AND    c1.char_col   = c.char_col
   );
```

I prefer the second variant as it also works with multiple "previous" rows matching in one of both related tables - which does not seem to apply to your case, but it's still the safer bet. Also typically a bit faster.

Comment: @Gracchus: It depends on your environment. Test both with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. Run a couple of times and take the best time to exclude caching artifacts. My money is on `EXISTS` ... Drop a line here as to the outcome if you don't mind.

Comment: @Gracchus: Nitpicking: `EXISTS` semi-joins are not exactly subqueries (that shows in the query plan). Results would be welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Inner join on counting_table.bigint-1 = other_table.bigint and counting_table.char = other_table.char

```
SELECT * 
FROM counting_table t1 
INNER JOIN other_table t2 
    ON t1.bigint_column-1 = t2.bigint_column 
    AND t1.character_column=t2.character_column
```