# Full text search on two tsvector columns

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, join, exists

I'm trying to do a full text search across two columns of two separate tables in PostgreSQL 9.4.2. The tables and columns are:

- article.article_title
- keyword.keyword

Where there is a many-to-many relationship between the two. I think I've got most of the way following this [blog post](https://blog.lateral.io/2015/05/full-text-search-in-milliseconds-with-postgresql/). However, I am struggling to formulate the query across the two columns. This query is returning results:

```
SELECT distinct title, pub_date, web_id, city_points, city_name FROM (
  SELECT article.article_title as title,
  article.pub_date as pub_date,
  article.web_id as web_id,
  string_agg(st_asText(city.geom), ', ') as city_points,
  string_agg(city.city, ', ') as city_name,
  article.title_tsv ||
  keyword.keyword_tsv
  as document 
  from article, article_keywords, keyword, article_cities, city
  where article.id = article_keywords.article_id
  and keyword.id = article_keywords.keyword_id
  and article.id = article_cities.article_id
  and city.id = article_cities.city_id
  GROUP BY article.id, keyword.id) p_search
WHERE p_search.document @@ to_tsquery('putin');
```

But I think the query suffers many of the same deficiencies from a previous question I asked [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107801/full-text-search-on-multiple-joined-tables?noredirect=1#comment196534_107801).

I am also trying to return the following columns in the query:

- article.pub_date
- article.web_id
- city.city_points
- city.city_name

I am pretty new to full text search - and SQL in general.
Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: I would seem that many of the same problems are in your new post. Have another look at my [previous answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107962/3684), I added more explanation about aggregating and `LEFT JOIN`. Also, you introduced `title_tsv` and `keyword_tsv` without explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In parts similar to my [last answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107962/3684):

```
SELECT a.id, a.article_title AS title, a.pub_date, a.web_id
       c.city_points, c.city_names
FROM   article a
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT ac.article_id AS id
        , string_agg(st_asText(c.geom), ', ') AS city_points
        , string_agg(c.city, ', ') AS city_names
   FROM   article_cities ac
   JOIN   city           c ON c.id = ac.city_id
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) c USING (id)
WHERE a.title_tsv @@ to_tsquery('putin')
OR    EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   article_keywords ak
   JOIN   keyword          k ON k.id = ak.keyword_id
   WHERE  ak.article_id = a.id
   AND    k.keyword_tsv @@ to_tsquery('putin')
   );
```

What's new here: we are only interested in the ***existence*** of a matching keyword, we are not even displaying them. (You may want to rethink that: shouldn't it become obvious from the result why the row was found?)

So I am using an `EXISTS` semi-join as alternative `WHERE` clause. Related:

- [Count where previous record exists in either of two tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64716/count-where-previous-record-exists-in-either-of-two-tables/64725#64725)

Once again we aggregate cities per `article_id` *before* joining to `article`, so we need no aggregate or `DISTINCT` in the outer `SELECT` since we do not multiply rows in the join.

And once again use `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` to include articles that are not linked to any cities at all.

Be aware that a list of comma-separated tables combined with `WHERE` conditions to join them is effectively the same as `[INNER] JOIN` on a join condition. [Basic in the manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN)

Comment: That's great thank you! I was just in the process of adapting you previous answer when this popped up! Cheers!